# Why font missing message shows up when using standalone and import packages only?

Tags: fonts, standalone, import, matlab-prettifier

Took me long time to find the cause of this one. From some bizzar reason, when I use standlone package, the font changes in the `lstlisting` of my Matlab code due to Latex not finding some fonts.

I am not able to find why and how to resolve it. When I do not include `standalone` and use `lstlisting` the fonts are found and as I want them. Here is MWE, which has `main.tex` as the parent, and `HW1.tex` as the child which is loaded using `import`.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{standalone}   
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{   
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breaklines         = false,
    escapechar         = `,
    mlshowsectionrules = true 
}
\begin{document}
\subimport*{./}{HW1}
\end{document}
```

Where the file `HW1.tex` is in the same folder and just lists some small Matlab code for illustration. Here it is

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}%
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
function nma_HW1_problem2_ECE719
%function to evaluate J at corner of the cube and do
%some syms caluclations.

syms u1 u2 u3;
J = 8*u1*u2*u3-4*u1*u2-4*u1*u3-4*u2*u3+2*u1+2*u2+2*u3-1;

%first find J value at all the corners, the coordinates  are
a      = {[-1 1] [-1 1] [-1 1]};
coords = allcomb(a{:});
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Now I compile main.tex using `pdflatex`, and this is what I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now when I do the same thing, but not use `import` and `standalone`, this is what I get. This is now the modified `main.tex`

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{   
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breaklines         = false,
    escapechar         = `,
    mlshowsectionrules = true 
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
function nma_HW1_problem2_ECE719
%function to evaluate J at corner of the cube and do
%some syms caluclations.

syms u1 u2 u3;
J = 8*u1*u2*u3-4*u1*u2-4*u1*u3-4*u2*u3+2*u1+2*u2+2*u3-1;

%first find J value at all the corners, the coordinates  are
a      = {[-1 1] [-1 1] [-1 1]};
coords = allcomb(a{:});
end
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Same code. Difference is that I put the code in the parent file instead of the child. I compile the above with pdflatex, and this is what I get

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Clearly it is different from the first case due to font missing issue.

I do see the font problems when I compile the case which has `standalone` and `import` in it. But I do not understand why it can't some fonts then, but it does find the fonts when I remove those packages. These are the warnings I get in the top case:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvdefinekeys.sty))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
(./HW1.tex

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmtt/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 11.

) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Some font shapes were not available, defaults substituted.

 ){/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}
</usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm1000.pfb></
```

The above messages do NOT show up in the second case.  But I do not know how to fix this.

TL 2015. Linux.  Here is the file list from the first case compile.

```
 *File List*
    book.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
    bk11.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
standalone.sty    2015/07/15 v1.2 Package to include TeX sub-files with preambl
es
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
currfile.sty    2013/02/01 v0.7b Provides the file path elements of the current
 input file
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
gincltex.sty    2011/09/04 v0.3 Include external LaTeX files like graphics
svn-prov.sty    2010/04/24 v3.1862 Package Date/Version from SVN Keywords
adjustbox.sty    2012/05/21 v1.0 Adjusting TeX boxes (trim, clip, ...)
 adjcalc.sty    2012/05/16 v1.1 Provides advanced setlength with multiple back-
ends (calc, etex, pgfmath)
trimclip.sty    2012/05/16 v1.0 Trim and clip general TeX material
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
collectbox.sty    2012/05/17 v0.4b Collect macro arguments as boxes
tc-pdftex.def    2012/05/13 v1.0 Clipping driver for pdftex
ifoddpage.sty    2011/09/13 v1.0 Conditionals for odd/even page detection
varwidth.sty    2009/03/30 ver 0.92;  Variable-width minipages
filemod-expmin.sty    2011/09/19 v1.2 Get and compare file modification times (
expandable; minimal)
  import.sty    2009/03/23  v 5.1
matlab-prettifier.sty    2014/06/19 v0.3 A package for prettyprinting Matlab so
urce code
textcomp.sty    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package
  ts1enc.def    2001/06/05 v3.0e (jk/car/fm) Standard LaTeX file
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
listings.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
 lstmisc.sty    2015/06/04 1.6 (Carsten Heinz)
listings.cfg    2015/06/04 1.6 listings configuration
  ts1cmr.fd    2014/09/29 v2.5h Standard LaTeX font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
     HW1.tex
 ***********
```

**Question is**: Why font missing message shows up when using standalone and import packages only?

Comment: Looks like the difference between `\rmfamily` and `\ttfamily`.

Comment: The 2nd code has `basicstyle=\ttfamily\small` which if you change to `\rmfamily`, it looks like the first output... But it would appear that the 1st version is not obeying the `\ttfamily` directive.  Maybe you have to respecify the `\lstset` in the child document.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes I actually also did respecify the \lstset in the child document. But standalone any way, strips all preamble from child document any way, and I still get same problem. I my actual code, I do specify the \lstset in all child documents, since I also compile these as standalone documents, and fonts come out correct then. The problem happens only when I combine them.

Comment: I see.  Some of my rambling is stream of consciousness as I slowly absorb what you did.  So one can generally ignore me with no ill consequences.

Comment: The issue does not show if the T1 encoding is not loaded, because the font is preloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the `\ttfamily` font available to the main document, which I did by typing `\setbox0=\hbox{\ttfamily}` as the last thing in the preamble, which leaves the document in `\rmfamily` while loading the `\ttfamily`.

There may be more official ways of providing for a font family.  With `Xelatex` for example, `\usepackage{fontspec} \newfontfamily{\ttfamily}{Courier New}` allows a tt font to be loaded without actually invoking the `\ttfamily` macro.

It would appear the `\subimport` can only work with a font if it is already available in the main document.  Thus, one must insure that the needed fonts are made available prior to the `\subimport` invocation.

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{standalone}   
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[numbered,framed]{matlab-prettifier}
\lstset{   
    style              = Matlab-editor,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    breaklines         = false,
    escapechar         = `,
    mlshowsectionrules = true 
}
\setbox0=\hbox{\ttfamily}
\begin{document}
\subimport*{./}{HW1}
\end{document}
```

In conjunction with `HW1.tex`, this will now produce the listing in `\ttfamily` font.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not related to standalone. You need it as your input has a preamble but you would get a similar problem with a normal input.

The problem is the \subimport* command. It changes the search pathes and so files in the texmf-tree are no longer found. This is normally not really a problem as you seldom input files from there in the document body. But the exception are fd-files: there are loaded when the font is used the first time. And so in your document the tt-font can't be set up as `t1cmtt.fd` is not found.

To avoid the problem: Either use the non-starred command `\subimport{./}{HW1}`, or force Latex to read `t1cmtt.fd` earlier by issuing `\ttfamily` in the main document.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both answers given solved the problem very well.

Comment: I wanted to mention, that I try to avoid the non-star version of subimport, since it has a bug.  When doing `\subimport` and if the file happened to be called `index` then a latex error is generated. I have many files called `index.tex`.  Only when the file is `index`. The problem goes away if the file is anything but `index.tex` that is being imported. I found this bug long time ago, and it is still not fixed.